# Webpack2 paths in dev console show actual file names

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass

We just migrated from webpack1 to webpack2, and there are some styles not rendering correctly after the upgrade.

As I look at the currently broken DOM elements in the dev console I am seeing that now the console is showing the path to the actual file, whereas in the older version it was just showing the file name. Also, when hovered over the filename it would show the relative path but starting with 'webpack:///.src/..'

Here are two separate screenshots of the devconsole to show what I mean:

[image]

And here are the two webpack config files:

### Version 2 (Giving file paths)

```js
import webpack from 'webpack';
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer';
import cssnano from 'cssnano';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
import config from '../config';
import _debug from 'debug';
const debug = _debug('app:webpack:config');
const paths = config.utils_paths;
const {__DEV__, __PROD__, __TEST__} = config.globals;

debug('Create configuration.');
const webpackConfig = {
  name: 'client',
  target: 'web',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      paths.base(config.dir_client),
      'node_modules'
    ],
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {}
};
// ------------------------------------
// Entry Points
// ------------------------------------
const APP_ENTRY_PATH = paths.base(config.dir_client) + '/main.js';

webpackConfig.entry = {
  app: __DEV__
    ? [APP_ENTRY_PATH, `webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=${config.compiler_public_path}__webpack_hmr`]
    : [APP_ENTRY_PATH],
  bootstrap: 'bootstrap-loader',
  vendor: config.compiler_vendor
};

// ------------------------------------
// Bundle Output
// ------------------------------------
webpackConfig.output = {
  filename: `[name].[${config.compiler_hash_type}].js`,
  path: paths.base(config.dir_dist),
  publicPath: config.compiler_public_path
};

// ------------------------------------
// Plugins
// ------------------------------------
webpackConfig.plugins = [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin(config.globals),
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    'jQuery': 'jquery',
    '$': 'jquery'
  }),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: paths.client('index.html'),
    hash: false,
    favicon: paths.client('static/favicon.ico'),
    filename: 'index.html',
    inject: 'body',
    minify: {
      collapseWhitespace: true
    }
  })
];

if (__DEV__) {
  debug('Enable plugins for live development (HMR, NoErrors).');
  webpackConfig.plugins.push(
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin()
  );
} else if (__PROD__) {
  debug('Enable plugins for production (UglifyJS).');
  webpackConfig.plugins.push(
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        unused: true,
        dead_code: true,
        warnings: false
      }
    })
  );
}

// Don't split bundles during testing, since we only want import one bundle
if (!__TEST__) {
  webpackConfig.plugins.push(
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      names: ['vendor']
    })
  );
}

// ------------------------------------
// This used to be called 'Pre-Loaders'. Now 'Rules' enforcing 'pre'
// ------------------------------------
webpackConfig.module.rules = [
  {
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    enforce: 'pre',
    loader: 'eslint-loader',
    include: /src/,
    options: {
      configFile: paths.base('.eslintrc'),
      emitWarning: __DEV__
    }
  }
];

// ------------------------------------
// Used to be called 'Loaders'.  Now 'Rules'
// ------------------------------------
// JavaScript / JSON
webpackConfig.module.rules.push({
  test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: [
    { loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        cacheDirectory: true,
        plugins: ['transform-runtime'],
        presets: __DEV__
          ? ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0', 'react-hmre']
          : ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0']
      }
    }
  ]
});

// Styles
const cssLoader = !config.compiler_css_modules
  ? {loader: 'css-loader', options: {sourceMap: true}}
  : {loader: 'css-loader',
    options: {
      modules: true,
      sourceMap: true,
      importLoaders: 1,
      localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
    }};

const postCssLoader = {
  loader: 'postcss-loader',
  options: {
    plugins: () => [
      autoprefixer({
        add: true,
        remove: true,
        browsers: ['last 2 versions']
      }),
      cssnano(
        {preset:
        ['default',
          {
            discardComments: {
              removeAll: true
            }
          }
        ]
        })],
    safe: true,
    sourceMap: true
  }
};

webpackConfig.module.rules.push({
  test: /\.scss$/,
  include: /src/,
  use: [
    'style-loader',
    cssLoader,
    postCssLoader,
    {loader: 'sass-loader', options: {sourceMap: true, includePaths: [paths.client('styles')]}}
  ]
});

webpackConfig.module.rules.push({
  test: /\.css$/,
  include: /src/,
  use: [
    'style-loader',
    cssLoader,
    postCssLoader
  ]
});

// Don't treat global SCSS as modules
webpackConfig.module.rules.push({
  test: /\.scss$/,
  exclude: /src/,
  use: [
    'style-loader',
    'css-loader?sourceMap',
    postCssLoader,
    {loader: 'sass-loader', options: {sourceMap: true, includePaths: [paths.client('styles')]}}
  ]
});

// Don't treat global, third-party CSS as modules
webpackConfig.module.rules.push({
  test: /\.css$/,
  exclude: /src/,
  use: [
    'style-loader',
    'css-loader?sourceMap',
    postCssLoader
  ]
});

// File loaders
/* eslint-disable */
webpackConfig.module.rules.push(
  { test: /\.woff(\?.*)?$/,  loader: 'url-loader?prefix=fonts/&name=[path][name].[ext]&limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff' },
  { test: /\.woff2(\?.*)?$/, loader: 'url-loader?prefix=fonts/&name=[path][name].[ext]&limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff2' },
  { test: /\.otf(\?.*)?$/,   loader: 'file-loader?prefix=fonts/&name=[path][name].[ext]&limit=10000&mimetype=font/opentype' },
  { test: /\.ttf(\?.*)?$/,   loader: 'url-loader?prefix=fonts/&name=[path][name].[ext]&limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream' },
  { test: /\.eot(\?.*)?$/,   loader: 'file-loader?prefix=fonts/&name=[path][name].[ext]' },
  { test: /\.svg(\?.*)?$/,   loader: 'url-loader?prefix=fonts/&name=[path][name].[ext]&limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml' },
  { test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,    loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192' }
)
/* eslint-enable */

export default webpackConfig;
```

### Version 1 (seems correct)

```js
import webpack from 'webpack';
import cssnano from 'cssnano';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
import config from '../config';
import _debug from 'debug';

const debug = _debug('app:webpack:config');
const paths = config.utils_paths;
const {__DEV__, __PROD__, __TEST__} = config.globals;

debug('Create configuration.');
const webpackConfig = {
  name: 'client',
  target: 'web',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    root: paths.base(config.dir_client),
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {}
};
// ------------------------------------
// Entry Points
// ------------------------------------
const APP_ENTRY_PATH = paths.base(config.dir_client) + '/main.js';

webpackConfig.entry = {
  app: __DEV__
    ? [APP_ENTRY_PATH, `webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=${config.compiler_public_path}__webpack_hmr`]
    : [APP_ENTRY_PATH],
  bootstrap: 'bootstrap-loader',
  vendor: config.compiler_vendor
};

// ------------------------------------
// Bundle Output
// ------------------------------------
webpackConfig.output = {
  filename: `[name].[${config.compiler_hash_type}].js`,
  path: paths.base(config.dir_dist),
  publicPath: config.compiler_public_path
};

// ------------------------------------
// Plugins
// ------------------------------------
webpackConfig.plugins = [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin(config.globals),
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      'jQuery': 'jquery',
      '$': 'jquery',
  }),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: paths.client('index.html'),
    hash: false,
    favicon: paths.client('static/favicon.ico'),
    filename: 'index.html',
    inject: 'body',
    minify: {
      collapseWhitespace: true
    }
  })
];

if (__DEV__) {
  debug('Enable plugins for live development (HMR, NoErrors).');
  webpackConfig.plugins.push(
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  );
} else if (__PROD__) {
  debug('Enable plugins for production (OccurenceOrder, Dedupe & UglifyJS).');
  webpackConfig.plugins.push(
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        unused: true,
        dead_code: true,
        warnings: false
      }
    })
  );
}

// Don't split bundles during testing, since we only want import one bundle
if (!__TEST__) {
  webpackConfig.plugins.push(
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      names : ['vendor']
    })
  )
}

// ------------------------------------
// Pre-Loaders
// ------------------------------------
webpackConfig.module.preLoaders = [{
  test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
  loader: 'eslint',
  exclude: /node_modules/
}];

webpackConfig.eslint = {
  configFile: paths.base('.eslintrc'),
  emitWarning: __DEV__
};

// ------------------------------------
// Loaders
// ------------------------------------
// JavaScript / JSON
webpackConfig.module.loaders = [{
  test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loader: 'babel',
  query: {
    cacheDirectory: true,
    plugins: ['transform-runtime'],
    presets: __DEV__
      ? ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0', 'react-hmre']
      : ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0']
  }
},
{
  test: /\.json$/,
  loader: 'json'
}
];


// Styles
const cssLoader = !config.compiler_css_modules
  ? 'css?sourceMap'
  : [
    'css?modules',
    'sourceMap',
    'importLoaders=1',
    'localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
  ].join('&');

webpackConfig.module.loaders.push({
  test: /\.scss$/,
  include: /src/,
  loaders: [
    'style',
    cssLoader,
    'postcss',
    'sass?sourceMap'
  ]
});

webpackConfig.module.loaders.push({
  test: /\.css$/,
  include: /src/,
  loaders: [
    'style',
    cssLoader,
    'postcss'
  ]
});

// Don't treat global SCSS as modules
webpackConfig.module.loaders.push({
  test: /\.scss$/,
  exclude: /src/,
  loaders: [
    'style',
    'css?sourceMap',
    'postcss',
    'sass?sourceMap'
  ]
});

// Don't treat global, third-party CSS as modules
webpackConfig.module.loaders.push({
  test: /\.css$/,
  exclude: /src/,
  loaders: [
    'style',
    'css?sourceMap',
    'postcss'
  ]
});

webpackConfig.sassLoader = {
  includePaths: paths.client('styles')
};

webpackConfig.postcss = [
  cssnano({
    autoprefixer: {
      add: true,
      remove: true,
      browsers: ['last 2 versions']
    },
    discardComments: {
      removeAll: true
    },
    safe: true,
    sourcemap: true
  })
];

// File loaders
/* eslint-disable */
webpackConfig.module.loaders.push(
  { test: /\.woff(\?.*)?$/,  loader: 'url?prefix=fonts/&name=[path][name].[ext]&limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff' },
  { test: /\.woff2(\?.*)?$/, loader: 'url?prefix=fonts/&name=[path][name].[ext]&limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff2' },
  { test: /\.otf(\?.*)?$/,   loader: 'file?prefix=fonts/&name=[path][name].[ext]&limit=10000&mimetype=font/opentype' },
  { test: /\.ttf(\?.*)?$/,   loader: 'url?prefix=fonts/&name=[path][name].[ext]&limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream' },
  { test: /\.eot(\?.*)?$/,   loader: 'file?prefix=fonts/&name=[path][name].[ext]' },
  { test: /\.svg(\?.*)?$/,   loader: 'url?prefix=fonts/&name=[path][name].[ext]&limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml' },
  { test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,    loader: 'url?limit=8192' }
)
/* eslint-enable */

export default webpackConfig;
```

The `config` file has not changed.  I have looked through the webpack2 docs and not sure what to set to get the style resolution as before.  I have tried `resolve.mainFiles` to point to what used to be the `resolve.root`, but that caused build errors.  I have also tried `output.devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate` to be `webpack:///[resource-path]?[loaders]` but the absolute path remains.

What is the significance of the 'webpack:///' file prefix versus the absolute file path?  Should I convert to the relative paths?  How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's about `source-maps` files?
So, when I was debugging JS, the file was loaded as `webpack:///` but then I used `Cmd+o` to open up the file via source-map, I was able to open up the file.

Comment: Yes definitely is source-map files, just not sure what changed in the config to see the absolute file paths...

Answer (score 0):

I looked for a while and handed it over to a colleague to later find out that css-loader is now using abs paths: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/releases/tag/v0.26.4

I've made a comment: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/pull/430#issuecomment-326002386